# How to work with xib files?

Tags: swift, xib

Im playing with this project [SquareCropViewController](https://github.com/annabd351/SquareCropViewController) It is a helper for crop images to square. Inside project there are two versions, one made with auto-layout and one that works purely programmatically. I want to use programmatic version and integrate in my project, which works with storyboards.

In programmatic version there are several files

> ProgrammaticController.swift
>   ProgrammaticController.xib

What is the sequence of actions to make it run in my project ? Do I have to create new viewcontroller and import xib inside it? If yes what is syntax ? I have never worked with xibs before and help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever try the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just instantiate the class if it's hooked up correctly in the xib.

```
var controller = ProgrammaticController()
navigationController.push(controller, animated:true)
```

The `file's owner's class` needs to be set to the actual class in the xib for that to work.